# F#, This value is not a function and the + operator

Tags: f#

This code:

```
let extractTime line  =
    let result =  Regex.Match(line, "(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)")
    let captureGroups = List.tail [for g in result.Groups -> g.Value]
    match captureGroups with
    | hrs::mins::secs::[] -> ((int hrs)*3600) + ((int mins)*60) +(int secs)
    | _ -> 0
```

Gives the error: "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" on this part of the code

```
((int mins)*60)
```

I bashed my head on it for a while, then added a space here

```
 + (int secs)
```

Taking out the spaces altogether also makes the error go away. e.g.

```
((int hrs)*3600)+((int mins)*60)+(int secs)
```

I don't understand why that space makes a difference. Can someone please explain it to me.

Comment: This is the same scenario as minus vs negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `+(int secs)` is interpreted as a value (`+` being a unary operator), in which case `((int mins)*60)` would need to be a function, for it to make sense. When there is no space, the following `+` can't possibly be interpreted as anything else than the binary operator. You can compare it with the following simple lines:

```
> 1 + 2;;
val it : int = 3
> 1 +2;;

  1 +2;;
  ^

stdin(2,1): error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
> 1 2;;

  1 2;;
  ^

stdin(3,1): error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
> 12;;
val it : int = 12
```